# delete node from linked list fails

Tags: c, linked-list

I am learning C and I try to make my own function which will delete a given node from the list. I have my struct:

```
typedef struct list
{
   int value;
   struct list *next;
} node;
```

then I create the nodes {1} {2} {3} {4},  `myList_ptr` is the pointer to the 1st node and then I code:

```
deletevalue(myList_ptr, 3);
```

where

```
void deletevalue(node *ptr, int value)
{
    node *temp = ptr;

    if(temp->value == value)
    {
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    else
    {
        while(temp->next->value != value)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        temp->next = temp->next->next;
    }
}
```

If I run the above command and print the list again I will get {1} {2} {4}. However if I run this command `deletevalue(myList_ptr, 1);` my 1st node isn’t deleted.
 **NOTES**

- I know that if I put as an argument an node that doesn’t exist, my program will break.
- Also, I know that I don't actually delete the node, but just hiding it.

To print the list I coded this:

```
void printlist(node *ptr)
{
    node *temp = ptr;

    printf("Print3 the list: [");
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf(" %d ",temp->value);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("]\n\n");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never update the original pointer passed to `deletevalue()`. After you change it you should return the new value.

```
node* deletevalue(node *ptr, int value)
```

And call it:

```
mylist = deletevalue(myList_ptr, 3);
```

Comment: Also, don't forget to `free()` the memory allocated to the node being deleted.

Comment: @anishsane OP mentioned that.

Comment: Oh sorry... I missed it.